# How to sync data between a Google Sheet and a Mysql DB?

Tags: python, mysql, google-apps-script, google-sheets

So I have a Google sheet that maintains a lot of data. I also have a MySQL DB with a huge junk of data. There is a vital piece of information in the Sheet that is also present in the DB. Both needs to be in sync. The information always enters the Sheet first. I had a python script with mysql queries to update my database separately.

Now the work flow has changed. Data will enter the sheet and whenever that happens the database has to updated automatically.

- After some research, I found that using the `onEdit` function of Google AppScript (I learned from [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/).), I could pickup when the file has changed.
- The Next step is to fetch the data from relevant cell, which I can do using [this](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets).
- Now I need to connect to the DB and send some queries. This is where I am stuck.

**Approach 1:**

Have a python web-app running live. Send the data via [UrlFetchApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app).This I yet have to try.

**Approach 2:**

Connect to mySQL remotely through appscript. But I am not sure this is possible after 2-3 hours of reading the docs.

So this is my scenario. Any viable solution you can think of or a better approach?

Comment: likely missed reading this part https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/jdbc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Connect directly to mySQL. You likely missed reading this part https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/jdbc

Answer (score 0):

Using [JDBC within Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/jdbc) will work if you have the time to build this yourself.

If you don't want to roll your own solution, check out [SeekWell](https://www.seekwell.io/?ref=so). It allows you to connect to databases and write SQL queries directly in Sheets. You can create a run a “Run Sheet” that will run multiple queries at once and schedule those queries to be run without you even opening the Sheet.

**Disclaimer**: I made this.

Comment: Its not open source so highly edoubt people will use